# Updating EF entities that are "code first from an existing database"

Tags: entity-framework-6, code-first

Is there a way to update Entity Framework entities after the initial code generation.

The scenario is a MySQL application was developed in Visual Studio Community 2013 and the "code first from an existing database" wizard was employed. At a later time, a new table was added to the database. I used MySQL Workbench to add the table. At this point, how can the entities be updated to include the database as it now stands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Our first step in EF7 is to provide a similar reverse engineer process to what’s available in EF6.x – and that is most likely what will be available for the initial release. We do also have some ideas around pulling in incremental updates to the model without overwriting any customization to previously generated code.

That's from this [2014 October post from Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx)

It seems then, that incremental reverse engineering is not an EF6 capability but they have "ideas" in this area for EF7.